# Angularjs and dynamic html content in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular application where I have a Datatable. In the datatable, I change cell content to contain html content.

In the code below, I change the cell content of the 5th column to have links. I wish to have a tooltip that informs the user about the link.
I am using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

```
var app = angular.module('smsmanagement', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('RecipientsController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $timeout, SweetAlert) {

var groupID = $routeParams.param;

    $('#table-recipients-view').DataTable({
        sDom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "recipients/dt",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.groupID = groupID; 
            }
         },
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
              var groupLink = '';
              // The number of columns to display in the datatable
              var cols = 6;

              var rowElementID = aData[(cols - 1)];

              groupLink = '<a href="#smsgroups/' + rowElementID + '" uib-tooltip="View group(s)">' + noOfGroups + '</a>';

            // Create a link in no of groups column
              $(nRow).children('td:eq(' + (cols - 2) + ')').html(groupLink);

          }
      });
  });
```

I have added the `uib-tooltip` directive in `groupLink` html content.

The problem is the tooltip does not appear. I've heard of using `$compile` but I am not quite sure on how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about using compile.

Try changing the following line:

```
$(nRow).children('td:eq(' + (cols - 2) + ')').html(groupLink);
```

To this:

```
$(nRow).children('td:eq(' + (cols - 2) + ')').html($compile(groupLink)($scope));
```

Also do not forget to inject `$compile` service to your controller.

**Edit**

This is definitely not the cleanest (or most AngularJS) way to solve the problem, but probably the easiest given your current setup. The best approach would probably be to create a new directive to deal with your data tables, but that is out of the scope of this question.

**Edit 2**

The general idea is to create directive to decouple DOM manipulation from your Controllers/Services.

Have a look at the official AngularJS documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to see how to create a directive. Your aim is probably something which would get the data in the controller via a service and pass that into your directive to deal with the DOM manipulation. For example like this:

```
<my-data-table data="dataVariableInScope"></my-data-table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: About your side note, maybe you can point me in the right direction on the cleaner (or more AngularJS) way of working with datatables.

Comment: I updated the answer with a general gist of what I meant by "cleaner" way.